# Show $Ext_R^1(R/(a), N) \cong N/aN$

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-functors

Let $R$ be a commutative PID. Let $0\neq a \in R$.

Then for any $R$-module $N$, we should have $Ext_R^1(R/(a), N)\cong N/aN$

I guess this should be a standard exercise, but I have no idea on how to pick an injective resolution of $N$ to start...

**EDIT:**

Ok I think I got it. Please correct me if I am wrong. $0\rightarrow R_1\rightarrow_\phi  R_0\rightarrow R/(a)\rightarrow 0$. $R_1, R_0$ both equal to $R$. $\phi: R_1\rightarrow R_0$ by $\phi(x)=ax$.

Applying $Hom(-, N)$ we have $0 \rightarrow Hom(R/(a), N) \rightarrow Hom(R_0,N)\rightarrow Hom(R_1,N)\rightarrow 0$.

Since $Ext^1(R/(a), N)=Hom(R_1,N)/Im(Hom(\phi, N))$, $Hom(R,N)\cong N$ and $Hom(\phi, N) = f \mapsto af$, we have $Ext^1(R/(a), N)=N/aN$.

Is the proof correct? I am not sure if I can have the rightmost arrow of the exact sequence, since $Hom(-, N)$ is left exact only.

Comment: Projective resolution of $R/(a)$ instead?

Comment: Hint: Consider $R \to R \to R/(a) \to 0$, where the first map is given by multiplication with $a$.

Comment: @Randall Updated the question with my attempt. Is the proof correct?

Comment: @MatheiBoulomenos Updated. Is the proof correct?

Comment: Yes, upon a careful identification of $\mathrm{Hom}_R(R,N)$ with $N$.

Comment: @Randall one more question here. I thought $Hom(-, N)$ is left exact only, but it seems to me that I need $Hom(R_1,N)\rightarrow 0$. Am I missing something?

Comment: After applying $\mathrm{Hom}_R(-,N)$, treat the resulting thing as a complex, not an exact sequence.  You need ker of the last mod image of the previous.  You can work out that kernel without having exactness.  Exactness of the last step would imply the previous is onto, which is both false and not necessary.

Comment: @Randall ok thanks!